# When I am trying to create a pipeline in amazon elastic transcoder using amazon console with IAM it gives me an error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-transcoder

user/abcd is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::453006003233:role/Elastic_Transcoder_Default_Role (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to attach the policy ElasticTranscoderDefaultRole with the particular group to which the IAM is added.